# Linux device driver's used minor numbers

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, device-driver

From the `/proc/devices` file it is possible to see the device drivers' major number.
Is there a way to list the minor numbers supported by a device driver?
I don't have the sources, I need a way to get info from a running Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Linux *does* keep track of which regions a certain driver allocated. Otherwise, the sharing of major number as it occurs over the vc, serial (maj 4) and ttyaux (maj 5) regions would not be doable without an extra dispatch module or something of that kind. In `fs/char_dev.c`, you will find

```
kobj = kobj_lookup(cdev_map, inode->i_rdev, &idx);
```

so indeed, Linux is looking up cdev objects by (major, minor), and not just (major).

See `/sys/dev/char/` for example:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mar 27 17:34 4:62 -> ../../devices/virtual/tty/tty62
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mar 27 17:34 4:63 -> ../../devices/virtual/tty/tty63
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mar 27 17:34 4:64 -> ../../devices/pnp0/00:06/tty/ttyS0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mar 27 17:34 4:65 -> ../../devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mar 27 17:34 4:66 -> ../../devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS2
...
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mar 27 17:34 4:79 -> ../../devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS15
```

Since I configured my kernel with `CONFIG_SERIAL_8250_NR_UARTS=16`, `CONFIG_SERIAL_8250_RUNTIME_UARTS=16`, I will see entries up to ttyS15 in the sysfs dir. This is what the device driver *registered* as a result of my config actions. This may be less than is reserved according to `Documentation/devices.txt`.

Answer (score -1):

Linux doesn't keep track of it.
When `open` is called with a minor number, this number is passed to the device driver. The driver can then do with it whatever it wishes.

A given driver may implement a table of minor numbers, each pointing to a state structure. But it may handle it otherwise.